# Calling inter-application process models

Tags: appian, lowcode

I have 2 applications in my Appian designer. Let's say app(a) and app(b).
Can I call process model of app(b) from some process model of app(a) directly through subprocess setup in Setup tab?

I've 2 applications in Appian designer : **booking** and **audit**
I want to call process model (*make audit entry*) of audit application, from process model (*save booking*) of booking application.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible. You can call any rule, constant or process model in the same Appian environment from any application.

Please pay attention to your security settings of the objects. For example also for the Datastore. The process models must be authorized for the corresponding users and groups.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you will be able to call the process modellers, rules, constants, records from other applications within the same development environment.

Do take note it is a good practise to store within the same environment unless you are able to classify them into groups or have rational reasons to have it in different application. For e.g. a valid reason is to perform a Appian Record Upgrade to the new syntax and enabling more record features, it will increase maintainability if you segment the Appian records into a records application.

Another pointer is to allow your users to be able to have the correct security access for the respective appian objects. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Applications in Appian are simply containers to manage objects. You can use any object within any object without worrying about which application contains them.

You do need to be sure that the user who is accessing those components/workflows has access to all those objects. Otherwise, they might see access issue errors.